# setBackgroundDrawable() is API 16 and my app requires a minimum API 9 I get no error when building

Tags: android

I have my app that requires SDK 9+ with code containing `setBackgroundDrawable()` which is API level 16. I did not get any error while coding or building the apk. but I got about 50 reports of this error happening in google analytics and a few reports in my developers console.

When I run the lint checker It also doesn't warn me. I am using eclipse. Is there a reason why it doesn't fail to compile like usually when you add a method that's not supported by the minimum API or is it simply an eclipse bug?

Comment: Did you choose to ignore the warning when you write the code in question?

Answer (score 6):

First of all you get no error when building since you probably are building with SDK 16+ and the method is there. But if you install the apk to a 2.1 Android phone it will throw a `MethodNotFound` Exception. So in the future ALWAYS install your apk on a min-target device to see if you didn't forget something. Min-Target basically is only a filter for the PLAY store (and for lint warnings, etc.)

AFAIK moving from `imageView.setBackground(...)` to `imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(...)` was just an api style design choice. So if you look at the source of Android SDK 18 you will see:

```
/**
     * Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background. If the
     * background has padding, this View's padding is set to the background's
     * padding. However, when a background is removed, this View's padding isn't
     * touched. If setting the padding is desired, please use
     * {@link #setPadding(int, int, int, int)}.
     *
     * @param background The Drawable to use as the background, or null to remove the
     *        background
     */
    public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
```

So for now its absolutely irrelevant if you use one or the other - but of course this COULD change (but it's unlikely it does in the future since it would break nearly every app done before SDK 16) - basically it's fine to use `setBackground()` even on SDK 18+

So if you want to be on the future-proof but ugly side you could use a version fork depicted by the other answers

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
//new code
} else {
//deprecated code
}
```

Just one thing, and maybe this is a personal style preference, I would not suppress Lint warnings with annotations like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

I like to keep the warnings since maybe later if I want to refactor/move to higher SDK I could easily get rid of these ugly switches.

---

**Update**:
[Google's v4 support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v4) contains helper classes for sdk boiler plate code. In this instance you would use:

```
ViewCompat.setBackground(view,drawable);
```

which handles the SDK check for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in eclipse or your eclipse is not working perfectly. But you can try project clean and try. But code wise you can try something like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setImage(ImageView imageView, BitmapDrawable bd) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
        imageView.setBackground(bd);
    } else {
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
    }
}
```

You can call this function along with ImageView and bitmap drawable.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski r u talking about if-else block ?

Comment: Yes. It's good habit, and you will not get "surprised" i.e. using languages with preprocessor or macros

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thanks edited. I usually do that but as it was one line code so i didn't put it.

Comment: It should be `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)` --- *greater equals 16 and not just greater 16*